# How to use react router dom in bootstrap navbar

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use the react router dom to navigate the links from the custom navbar. following is the code structure.

cust navbar contains all the links which needs to be routed.

**CustNavbar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";

import "./socialstyle.css";
import "./links.css";

import "./alldata.js";

export default class CustNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="/abc">abc</Navbar.Brand>

        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto links">
            <Nav.Link href="/alldata">Alldata</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

**alldata.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";

export default class Alldata extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Alldata</h1>
        <p>content</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactBootstrap, {
  Navbar,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  NavDropdown
} from "react-bootstrap";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";   
import "./carosel.css";
import "./socialstyle.css";
import "./links.css";
import "./alldata.js";


import styled from "styled-components";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {
  faYoutube,
  faFacebook,
  faTwitter
} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons";


export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.fragment>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
          <Navbar.Brand href="/abc">abc</Navbar.Brand>

          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto links">
              <Nav.Link href="/alldata">Alldata</Nav.Link>
              
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

        <Carousel>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img className="d-block w-100" src={slide01} alt="First slide" />
            <div class="absolute-div">
              <Carousel.Caption>
                <h2>
                  {" "}
                  hello1.{" "}
                </h2>
              </Carousel.Caption>
            </div>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img className="d-block w-100" src={slide02} alt="Second slide" />
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h2>hello2 </h2>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>

          <Carousel.Item>
            <img className="d-block w-100" src={slide03} alt="Third slide" />
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h2> hello3 </h2>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
        </div>
      </React.fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import CustNavbar from "./Components/CustNavbar";
import Alldata from "./Components/alldata";
import Home from "./Components/home";  
import Carasel from "./Components/carosel";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <CustNavbar />
         <Route path="/abc" exact={true} component={Home} />
         <Route path="/Alldata" exact={true} component={Alldata} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

now the issue is, the respective links are not loading their respective data. I mean even if i load `/abc` it loads all the content and also with `/alldata` . Seems some issue with router dom but not able to figure out.

some code refactoring needs to be done in order to load proper content?

Comment: please suggest/help. this is blocker

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.
it was due to the wrong path configuration. we need to use the `switch` around the router